# Mimetic word for describing "an action of walking slowly in exhaustion, despair, and sadness"

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I just came across a mimetic word, "scoot", in a cartoon named "To love and be loved", and found the dictionary definition of it, which is:

> "go or leave somewhere **quickly**"

It doesn't seem to fit in this context, where, the girl feels depressed and tired after a phone call with her dad, since he always puts his decision first over hers and tries to control her.
Especially if you see the drawings of her, **walking slumped and depressed**, I feel like I need a different mimetic word to describe the action of her walking/footsteps appropriately.

What would be the right word for it? Or is there a different meaning of "scoot" other than the one I wrote above that makes the word right fit for the scene? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I know of no markedly different meaning for _scoot_ and it definitely seems wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some synonyms for [trudge](https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/trudge). You could look up the usage of 'plod' and 'maunder'.

'Slouch' is useful but doesn't, on its own, suggest walking.

You could focus on the adverb: walking wearily, for example.

Answer (score 1):

"Trudge" is the best fit I can find, although it implies slowness and potentially exhaustion but not sadness.

The best way to convey the entire meaning is probably add an adverb like "trudge despondently".